# Should a workflow trigger via Explorer View?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, open-with-explorer

I have a simple workflow set up that sends out an email when a specific document is updated. All the workflow does is check the filename and then sends out or stops the workflow based on that filename. The user that normally updates the file has reported that the emails no longer go out as about two months ago (the document is normally updated every month or so).

After some troubleshooting, we figured out that the workflow wasn't even starting when he does it, but works normally when I do it or have someone with permissions equal to his do it. I then went to his desk and found that he was updating the file by opening Explorer View and dragging the new version of the document from his local desktop to the library.

I had him try via the SharePoint UI instead of Explorer View, and the email went out normally. He reports, however, that he has always done it the same way (using Explorer View), and nothing has changed on the farm (no updates or anything).

I've done some googling, but I'm finding results that say both YES - a workflow should trigger that way, and NO - they shouldn't. I'd like to clarify that point before proceeding.

**Should a SharePoint 2010 workflow (set to fire when a document is created or modified) trigger if a document is replaced/overwritten using Explorer View?**

---

Environment: SharePoint 2013 Enterprise, SPD workflows using 2010 template